# Spacy rules based match not returning match as expected

Tags: spacy

I am try to do a match on date string in spacy and the two parts are matching individually but the combined result is not returning match.

```
rule_patterns = [

    {
        "label": "DATE_COMBINED",
        "pattern": [
            {'TEXT': {"REGEX": "^[0-9](st|nd|rd|th)", 'LENGTH': 3}},
            {'POS': 'PROPN'},
            {'IS_PUNCT': True, 'OP': '?'},
            {'IS_DIGIT': True}
        ]
    },
    {
        "label": "DATE_TEXT",
        "pattern": [
            {'POS': 'PROPN'},
            {'IS_PUNCT': True, 'OP': '?'},
            {'IS_DIGIT': True}
        ]
    },

    {
        "label": "DATE_NUM",
        "pattern": [
            {'TEXT': {"REGEX": "^[0-9](st|nd|rd|th)", 'LENGTH': 3}}
            ]
    },


]

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm", disable=["ner"]) 
ruler = EntityRuler(nlp)
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
ruler.add_patterns(rule_patterns)
nlp.add_pipe(ruler)

doc = nlp(text) 
for ent in doc.ents:
  print(ent.text, ent.label_)
```

The string to match is

> the 4th January, 2013

The output of the run is

```
4th DATE_NUM
January, 2013 DATE_TEXT
```

I am not able to get the match on DATE_COMBINED any things I am doing wrong

**UPDATE**
I notice when i print all token the space between 4th and January is also considered as token.

```
[
            {'TEXT': {"REGEX": "^[0-9]{1,2}(st|nd|rd|th)$", 'LENGTH': 3}},
            {"IS_SPACE": True},
            {'POS': 'PROPN'},
            {'IS_PUNCT': True, 'OP': '?'},
            {'IS_DIGIT': True}
        ]
```

This works

Comment: Just ran your code and got `4th January, 2013 DATE_COMBINED` for the `text='the 4th January, 2013'`

Comment: Thanks I noticed when i print all token the space between 4th January is also shown as token. I believe some how the spacy is not marking this space as white listed space.

Comment: Yes, in the raw body the non-breaking space is seen. I advise using `$` at the end of the first regex to match the complete token with the regex and make the `{'IS_SPACE': True}` optional with `{'IS_SPACE': True, 'OP': '?'}`. Actually, the first regex should be fixed, see my answer below.

Comment: If my answer solved the problem, please consider accepting.

Answer (score 1):

The whitespace between the `4th` and `January` is a non-breaking space, `\x0A`.

The simplest solution is to normalize these spaces to regular space:

```
text = text.replace("\xA0", " ")
```

Else, you may add `{'IS_SPACE': True, 'OP': '?'}` to the pattern rules to match **optional** non-token segmenting whitespace:

```
"label": "DATE_COMBINED",
"pattern": [
     {'TEXT': {"REGEX": "^[0-9]+(?:st|[nr]d|th)$", 'LENGTH': 3}},
     {'IS_SPACE': True, 'OP': '?'},
     {'POS': 'PROPN'},
     {'IS_PUNCT': True, 'OP': '?'},
     {'IS_DIGIT': True}
]
```

Note the first `^[0-9]+(?:st|[nr]d|th)$` pattern now contains `$` at the end so as to match the token as a full string (`$` matches the end of string) and means:

- `^` - start of a token
- `[0-9]+` - 1 or more digits
- `(?:st|[nr]d|th)` - `st`, `n` or `r` followed with `d` or `th` substrings
- `$` - end of string.